# Reading grayscale .jpeg image in C++ without using external libraries?

Tags: c++, image, image-processing

I am a beginner.

I need to know if there is any way to read a grayscale .jpeg image and generate the pixel array in C++ without using external image processing libraries. If it's possible, then how?

I have read other answers related to this, but all of them recommended using an external library.

Also, I just need to generate the pixel array containing values between (0-255).

Comment: checkout libjpeg's example code.

Comment: Why do you want to avoid external libraries and reinvent them?

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch As I mentioned I am new at this and may be I don't know what I am talking about. I was just looking for any easy way to avoid reading the documentation and external source code .

Comment: @Till Can you please give me the exact link ? Thank You .

Comment: Reading documentation and existing source code is a lot easier than redesigning your own library, coding it, debugging it, ....

Comment: @AmitKumar If you want to read a JPEG image by yourself, you can try read the JPEG specification - commonly known as "ITU T.81". You can search this on the internet. (URLs might be removed for DMCA takedown notice, but for your convenience [here it is](http://www.w3.org/Graphics/JPEG/itu-t81.pdf). )

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can read it but then, you will have to also decode the input to get raw pixels.  You will have to read the header in the file, and once you start reading the raw data, you will have to apply inverse DCT (Discrete Cosine Transform) to get the raw pixels.  That is why, it is better to use an external library to read the image.

Comment: Which library do you suggest is the most easy and hassle free to use ?

Comment: libjpeg is the obvious choice.  However, depending on your application, you may want to use OpenCV or ImageMagick or whatever else you like.